# What is channelUrl

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we need to create a channel.html on our server to use Facebook JS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052734/why-do-we-need-to-create-a-channel-html-on-our-server-to-use-facebook-js-sdk)

following this guide I was able to enter the login of facebook in one of my php page
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/
But I do not understand how to change this line. what is it?

```
channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read out this: [How-To: Optimize Social Plugin Performance](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/)

Comment: Please summarize links when you post them. Even though it's bad form to move resources without leaving a forwarding address, people do it all the time. The top two links in Google for my particular question are Stack Overflow posts where the person answered with this exact link... which is now broken.

Comment: Link above is no longer found

Comment: Here is the working link https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/02/how-to--optimize-social-plugin-performance/